# Preimage of a set under floor function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

How would I interpret the pre-image of $U = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ under the function $g(x) = \left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$? Friend says it's $[1,2)$ but I just can't undrstand it...

Comment: Hint: the floor function takes only integer values, and the only integer in $U$ is $1\,$, so the answer is the same as for $g^{-1}\left(\{ 1 \}\right)$.

Comment: Hmm, I understand that I think, but isn't the preimage basically saying "what values will I get now if I let our function $g(x)$ to equal values in $U$? Isn't it like saying an element of the pre-image includes the solution to $g(x) = \frac{3}{4}$? Which there isn't a solution to.

Comment: So the pre-image is what ever set you're using. The image on the other hand are integers. now you can be very cheeky with this because the all of the image doesn't have to hit by the function.

Comment: @Analytical13 By definition $g^{-1}\left(U\right) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid g(x) \in U\}\,$. Note that $U$ does not *have* to be included in the range of $g$, and it isn't in this case, in fact $g(\mathbb{R}) \cap U = \{ 1 \}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

System won't let me write a comment so I'll write an answer instead.

Think in the following steps might help:

1. What value can $g(x)$ take?  --Integers.
2. Then, what value in $(1/2,3/2)$ can $g(x)$ take?  --$1$.
3. What is $g^{-1}(1)$?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. But then that means the interval given in the OP as the prei-image is incorrect right? Because (for example) we can't have 1.1 to be in the pre-image, only 1?

Comment: The interval is correct. Although you don't have 1.1 in the image, you do have 1 in the image.

Comment: Sorry but the $\lfloor \frac{1}{2} \rfloor = 0$

Comment: @Sentinel135, I didn't quite understand what you're saying

Comment: @Sentinel135: $\frac12$ is not part of the proposed pre-image.

Comment: the floor of rational values less than one is zero. So if we take $U:= \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\}$ the image can't be $\{1\}$, because $0 \in img(g)$

Comment: then what is $U$?

Comment: @Sentinel135 It's real numbers between 1/2 and 3/2

Comment: Now big question would $g: A \to U$ be bijective? If not would $g^{-1}$ even exist?

Comment: @Sentinel135 no it's not bijective, there're different $x$ that corresponds to the same $g(x)$

Comment: Exactly Since it's neither one to one nor onto (a.k.a injective and surjective), it would literally make no sense to find $g^{-1}$ as such an object only exists for bijective functions. This is why I was assuming that $g:U\to A$  as that would make more sense. In that situation the pre-image would be $U$. However, if you are correct that $g: A \to U$ this would mean that $A$ could be any set such that $x\in A$ with $g(x)=1$. This would indeed mean that $A \subset [1,2)$.

Comment: g: U-> A is not at all true and a completely incorrect assumption..  We want $g:W \rightarrow K \subset U$ where $U = (1/2, 3/2)$ and $W = g^{-1}(K)$.  In this case $K$ = {1} $\subset U$ and $g^{-1}(K) = g^{-1} (1) = [1,2)$.

Comment: @Sentinel135, I see what you mean, however, in many scenarios you don't need a bijection to define $g^{-1}$

Comment: @Oliver apparently so. It never occurred to me that there actually exists left and right inverses. I'll have to have a chat with my abstract algebra professor about the statement: "A function is bijective iff it has an inverse." Which we proved in class... with that said fleablood corrected the issue with his comment above. However, there still is the issue that $W \subset [1,2)$ and not necessarily $W = [1,2)$ as **any** subset of $[1,2)$ would have $g(w)=1$ for all $w\in W$. For example  $W:=\{ \sqrt{2}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this depends on what "pre-image" means.

The Pre-image of $U = g^{-1}(U) = \{x \in \mathbb R|g(x) \in U\}$.

Therefore $g: g^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$.  ***BUT*** Note that the image of the pre-image is *not* necessarily all of $U$.

It's possible that $g:g^{-1}(U) \rightarrow K \subsetneq U$ where $K = \{g(s)|s \in g^{-1}(U)\}$.

Which is precisely what happens here.

$S=g^{-1}(\frac 12, \frac 32) = \{x \in \mathbb R| \lfloor x \rfloor \in (\frac 12, \frac 32)\} =$

$ \{x \in \mathbb R| \frac 12 < \lfloor x \rfloor < \frac 32\} =$

$ \{x \in \mathbb R|  \lfloor x \rfloor  =1\} =$

$[1,2)$.

And that's all there is to it.

Now it *is* true that $g(S) = \{1\} \ne (\frac 12, \frac 32)$.  But that is not relevent.

It is NOT true that $g(pre-image(U)) = U$.  It is *only* nescessary that $g(pre-image(U)) \subset U$.  It *is* nescessary that if $g(x) \in U$ then $x \in pre-image (U)$.  But that is all.

So... yes, the question is misleading.  There are not any $\frac 12 < x < 1$ nor any $1< y < \frac 32$ so that $g(k) = x$ or $g(k) = y$ and the pre-image of $(\frac 12, \frac 32)$ is the *same* pre-image of $\{1\}$ and the *same* pre-image of $(1,2)$.  The points that are not mapped to don't affect *anything* and are totally irrelevent.